# PHP - redirect after submitting a form not redirecting to another page

Tags: php, forms, post-redirect-get

I am trying to capture the values a user submits in the form below and carry the values to another web page for processing. When clicking the submit button on the form, no redirect takes place. Any advice? Thanks!

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$lowestPrice = ($_POST['lowestPrice']);
$highestPrice = ($_POST['highestPrice']);

header("Location: URL that carries $lowestPrice and $highestPrice values to another page     
for processing");
}

<form name="priceRange" method="post" action= "<?php echo $_server['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Lowest Price<input type="text" name="lowestPrice" id="lowestPrice"> &nbsp &nbsp
Highest Price<input type="text" name="highestPrice" id="highestPrice"><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: You are seperating your PHP from HTML, right? Plus, tell me you're not actually using `header("Location: URL that carries $lowestPrice and $highestPrice values to another page for processing");`

Comment: You may be going about this the wrong way. 

In the action on the form, you can simply specify another PHP script that will have the POST data

Comment: If you want to capture info from one page to another using header, you can use sessions, which is much simpler.

Comment: and why not just do the processing in the if block? Why does the processing have to be on another page?

Answer (score 0):

`$_server['PHP_SELF'];` => `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Also add `exit` after the `header();`.

Comment: Good catch, however do explain why `$_SERVER` --- There is a reason. ;-) No sense posting an answer if you can't explain it, since it's a very important one at that.

Comment: Because the variable name is case-sensitive?:P

Comment: No, that's not a valid explanation. It is to a certain extent, but it's not "the" reason. I will let you Google it.

Comment: SERVER is a PHP global containing server request information. Since variables in PHP are case sensitive $_server != $_Server != $_SERVER

Comment: A [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) actually. @AzizSaleh --- You didn't give the person a chance to Google it.

Comment: Oh well, the magic knowledge that SERVER is a part of the superglobals is a must-have, but whatever. Was thinking about the deprecated `register_globals` but not that easy one, doh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.php.net/http_build_query

```
$requestStr = http_build_query ($_POST);
header("Location: URL.php?".$requestStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

POST variables get carried "not as part of the URL". However, GET variables are moved forward as part of the URL.

For GET

```
header("Location: someURL.php?lowestprice=".$lowerprice."&highestprice=".$highestprice);
```

}

For POST

```
header("Location: someURL.php");
```

in someURL.php
Call the variables in start of the redirected page for processing.

```
$lowestvar = $_POST['lowestPrice']; $highestvar = $_POST['highestPrice'];
```

Comment: Thanks! Calling the variables in the 'someURL.php page works. But using the header() is not working with post or get. Seems simple, but it isn't working. Maybe there is a glitch somewhere!

Comment: You should only call the page in header. And declare POST variables in the next PHP page.